# Disable middle mouse click and drag function in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, firefox, mousewheel

i'd like to disable middle mouse click and drag function for whole html doc. I tried this:

**html:**

```
<body onmousedown="aabb(this.event);">
```

**script:**

```
function aabb(e)
{
    event.preventDefault();
}
```

It works fine in Chrome and IE but Firefox apparently don't know how to deal with it.
Do you have any solutions?

Comment: Why are you even trying to block the middle mouse click?

Answer (score 3):

You defined e, but you use event.

HTML:

```
<body onmousedown="aabb(event);">
```

JavaScript:

```
function aabb (event) { 
    event.preventDefault(); 
}
```

But since you are using jQuery, why are you not doing it the jQuery way?

```
$(document.body).on("mousedown", function (e) { e.preventDefault(); } );
```

Answer (score -1):

Have you try .off() or unbind() ?

http://api.jquery.com/unbind/

http://api.jquery.com/off/

Comment: OP wants to prevent the default action, not a handler he has attached.

Comment: Actually i didn't can you give me example in my situation?